# Making ImageView Depend on Image Size But not Fixed ImabeView

Tags: swift, image, imageview

I want to make a dynamic imageView which can depend on the image ratio inside(image's ratio different).
And the imageView width follow the  screen width(or the tableView width), image's height is resize by the image inside.
My storyboard looks like that:[image]

[image]
The imageView mode set Aspect Fit.
How can the image's width be the same with tableView(or screen width)?
And to resize both the height of the image and tableView ??(don't leave yellow margin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you add a Y constraint, e.g. use the pin board to constraint the vertical spacing to top layout guide, and then use control drag to the view controller icon, to centre the imageView horizontally, then when you set the image for the imageView, it should automatically resize to the size that the image is as you won't have set any size or aspect ratio constraints. If you wanted, you could set a constraint to say you always want it to be an equal height from the table view, however, this could cause the image to look stretched if you do not set the aspect ratio.

Comment: I do what you said:
Step1:use the pin board to constraint the vertical spacing to top layout guide.
Step2:centre the imageView horizontally
Step3:set the image for the imageView automatically resize to the size that the image is
Step4(optional):set a constraint to say you always want it to be an equal height from the table view
Can I ask what View Mode should I select?I selected "Scale To Fit",when I chose the image which width > height,It looks well.
But if I chose the image which height > width,then I looks strange to the original image.   
http://imgur.com/a/o6ARo

Comment: Ah, based on your example, I would recommend that you do not add any x constraints apart from "centre horizontally" as this could cause image stretching. Do not select "Scale To Fit", however, if you are going to be using many different size images, using Auto layout ( as far as I know) there is no way to make them all the same size and all look good, unless you programmatically add constraints based on image size. I can help you with this if you want.

Comment: Thank You ! I put my Demo on the dropbox
https://www.dropbox.com/s/m3qr6uc2bqmms7n/ImageViewDemo.zip?dl=0
and there are some pics in the Assets.Some of them w>h,others h>w.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fix the height and width of imageView.
Using constraints just set the x, y position, it automatically becomes resizable according to image size.

Comment: After I deleted the aspect 4:3,and tried.It looks like that:http://imgur.com/a/o6ARo
Still something wrong...looks strange